# Check a list contains given elements

Tags: python, string, list

I want to check if my list's first four elements are digits.
what i did is as follows:

```
myList = ['0', '3', '2', '7', 'O', 'K', 'P']
if myList[0:4] in string.digits:
  print('okay')
else:
  print('wrng')
```

But this gives the following error.

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Replace the conditional with `if all(d in string.digits for d in myList[0:4]):`

Comment: `''.join(myList[:4]).isnumeric()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that you can't do `some_list in some_string` - after all, a list consists of characters, not lists, so it's pointless. You want to check if *all* the characters in your list are in the string, so:

```
if all(ch in string.digits for ch in myList[:4]):
```

The `0` in `0:4` is not needed, it's the default.